# Insert integers into 2d array

Tags: java

```
private void enterbtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        int [][] array = new int [4][4]; // my array

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++)
                array[i][j]= ;// use for feeding the code 
        }
        popfield.setText(Arrays.deepToString( array ) );     
 }
```

I want to insert integers into 2d array via 2 textfields one for columns and one for rows elements via two text fields xfield and yfield

Comment: Try to better specify what you mean with "one for columns and one for rows elements" - 2D array is like a grid / matrix, there are no "columns" and "rows", just 1st index and 2nd index (yes, in "paper version" it could be like column and row, but it depends, which one you will see as "row" and which one as "column" :) 

You mean to use values of "xfield" and "yfield" for dimension (like create grid with dimensions "X*Y" or ? .. 
Etc, etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So..  For **create 2D int** array:

```
    //int 2 dimensional array
    int[][] array = null;

    //your fields values
    final int xFieldVal = 5;
    final int yFieldVal = 7;

    //values to fill into array
    final int minArrayVal = 50;
    final int maxArrayVal = 100;

    //create matrix / grid with dimensions (xFieldVal x yFieldVal)
    array = new int[xFieldVal][yFieldVal];
```

(that creates recangle xFieldVal x yFieldVal- or Y*X..)

While you have **rectangle array you can acces** to all value for filling eg. like that:

```
    //random generator
    Random rnd = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < xFieldVal; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < yFieldVal; j++) {
            //generate new int in interval
            array[i][j] = minArrayVal + rnd.nextInt(maxArrayVal- minArrayVal+ 1);
        }
    }
```

While you will **dont have rectangle array** (you can have eg. just 1st dimension fixed, and 2nd not- I mean each "row" can have difference "columns" count), you have to use that loop:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(array[i][j] + " ");
        }
        //printing next line
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Eg. to **find min and max value**, you can use that:

```
    //set on the max possible (every value should be less than that)
    int min=Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    //set on the min possible (every value should be more than that)
    int max=Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    //iteration through 1st index (eg. iteration through rows)
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        //iteration through 2nd index of 1st index (eg. through all columns)
        for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
            //compare and assign if array value is less than actual found min
            if(min > array[i][j]){
                min = array[i][j];
            }
            //compare and assign if array value is more than actual found max
            if(max < array[i][j]){
                max = array[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Btw that finding max and min value is from every value in the grid :)

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you understand what a 2D array is

think of it as a grid. you insert into a single cell at a time.

a single cell belongs to a row and a column hence has a row number and column number...like an excel work book? cell b5?

so if you want to input numbers all you gotta do is have a single textfield lets call it `txt`

the rest is as follows

```
private void enterbtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)                                         
{

    int [][] array = new int [4][4]; // my array

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)

    {

        for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++)

            array[i][j]= Integer.parseInt(txt.getText());// use for feeding the code 



    }

    popfield.setText(Arrays.deepToString( array ) );

}
```

Comment: First of all thanx alot for answering me, secondly i actually wanted to enter the 2d array elements from the text field with spaces between them when i  enter the int numbers the whole number is considered as just one and not more elements are used

Comment: im sorry bro i dont understand what you're saying